# Xamarin.Forms.Labs - MediaPicker and Camera not showing image on Android - bitmap too large

Tags: android, bitmap, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using the MediaPicker, and whenever I call TakePhotoAsync or SelectPhotoAsync with CameraMediaStorageOptions set (MaxPixelDimension = 500), I get a
"Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture" error when trying to set the file to an "Image" object. I've only tested this on Android.

Anyone else having the same problem or know of a workaround?